# How to find the limit points in a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Let  $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space where $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$, $\tau=\{\emptyset,X,\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$. Then what are limit points of the set  $A = \{a,c,d\}$?

Is it true that $b$, $c$ and $d$ are limit points?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition), a point $x$ in $X$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ different from $x$ itself. We can directly check that  $b$, $c$ and $d$ are limit points of $A$, and $a$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

For b check just that intersection of all open sets which containing b has non empty intersection with A excluding {b}. Same apply for C and d. As you can note that singleton open set has intersection with A excluding that point is empty. So a cannot limit point of A.